# Storing a dictionary in a dictionary in Erlang

Tags: dictionary, erlang

I have a dictionary which I use to store another dictionary using the name of a parameter.

I get a right hand side mismatch error.

here is my code

```
handle_cast({setState, Id}, State) ->
Id0 = dict:new(), 
DQueue = queue:new(),
UQueue = queue:new(),
Id1 = dict:store(dQueue, [DQueue], Id0),
Id2 = dict:store(uQueue, [UQueue], Id1),
Id3 = dict:store(dSpeed, [], Id2),
Id4 = dict:store(uSpeed, [], Id3),
D = dict:store(Id, [Id4], State),
State = D,
{noreply, State};
```

Im not sure where the error comes from. I thought it might be because I store Id as the key in the main dictionary with the new internal dictionary as the value.

I need the name of the internal dictionary to be the value of the Id as there will be many of them and I need to access them by Id later.

Am I setting the dictionary up correctly? Does erlang allow dictionaries to hold dictionaries?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without trying the code, my bet is that you badmatch when doing `State = D` given that `State` is already bound in the function's head. On top of this, `USpeed` and `DSpeed` should be undefined unless you copy/pasted your function wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I changed some things. Its part of a uni project :P I will edit those now thanks. So I should just make it e.g. NewState = D. {noreply, NewState}. ? ;)

Comment: either that or just `{noreply, D}`

Comment: How are these effecting memory? Creating a new Dict when storing, passing in the old dict? Or does it overwrite it immediately?

Comment: It overwrites. The thing is, when you update a dictionary (or any other tree-based structure) in Erlang, it will replace only the nodes traversed up to the point where the replacement is made. All other elements of the dict are shared. Creating the dicts Id1, Id2, Id3 and Id4 should only rewrite `log(N)` nodes on average in the long run. When replacing the tree in the server's state, references to the old tree will be lost, but some of its nodes will still be shared by the new one. Garbage collection will eventually reclaim that lost memory without any pause to the system.

Answer (score 3):

How about a rewrite:

```
handle_cast({setState, Id}, State) ->
   D = dict:from_list([{dQueue, [queue:new()]},
                       {uQueue, [queue:new()]},
                       {dSpeed, []},
                       {uSpeed, []}],
   {noreply, D};
```

Which is simpler to read, avoids naming trouble and is about the same speed.

Comment: This is really good. As later on in that module I store dictionaries in the main dictionary and the naming convention was a struggle to follow.